# How did C become standardized?

Tags: c, standards

Since C was developed as a general purpose language and is not owned by a private company in general, can the standardization process be explained?

I mean how did this standardization process come about?

Comment: You have to distinguish between owning copyright on an implementation (many companies and open source projects own copyright on C compilers; I think Novell owns the copyrights on the original compiler), owning the copyright on the standard text, and owning patents that could impact the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [whole page dedicated to information on the C standard committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) aka JTC1/SC22/WG14.

Actually JTC1 is the  IT standards group and SC22 is the programming langages standards sub committee and WG14 is the C standards sub sub committee.

Also, the [History section of the C Programming Language on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#History) is very informative.

[update] Here is the [most complete history of C I can find from Bell Labs](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html).

Comment: Would be nice to have history/notes of K&R C / "The C Programming Language" / C89 / C99. It wasn't always such a formal comittee.

Comment: @pst - Dennis Richie left a bunch of notes at [his old home page at Bell Labs](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/) containing early Unix and C language info.

Comment: Yeah, I actually just found a link to the CHistory page at bell labs.

Comment: A historian would also look at computer magazines of the period.  P.J. Plauger wrote a "Programming on Purpose" (IIRC) column for "Computer Language", and discussed some of went on in standardization in his column.